# \eqref inside \section

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
 \label{func1a}
  U(X,Y)
  &= 2X + 5Y,\\
 \label{func1b}
  U(X,Y)
  &= (XY)^{0.5},\\
 \label{func1c}
  U(X,Y)
  &= \min(X,Y).
\end{align}

\section{The function~\eqref{func1a}}

\end{document}
```

This produces the following warnings:

```
Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing `\hbox' on input line 20.


Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing `\mathsurround' on input line 20.


Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing `\z@' on input line 20.


Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing `\unskip' on input line 20.


Package hyperref Warning: Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):
(hyperref)                removing `\@@italiccorr' on input line 20.
```

How do I fix this?

P.S. The warnings are caused by [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref).

Comment: They are not errors that need fixing: hyperref is just telling you what it is doing

Comment: `warning` is not `error`. Don't worry.

Comment: You can use `hyperref`'s `\texorpdfstring` macro to avoid those warnings.

Comment: @Jubobs How would you use that? I have had a look at it but couldn't figure out how to use it in this case.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So I shouldn't try to get rit of the warnings?

Comment: You could ignore the warnings, or define eqref to silently make the pdf bookmark string or just use `\section{The function~(\ref{func1a})}` as `\ref` doesn't generate warnings, but in any case the output is the same

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`hyperref` is able to cope with `\ref` but not `\eqref`; here's how you can teach it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\def\eqref#1{(\ref{#1})}}


\begin{document}

\begin{align}
 \label{func1a}
  U(X,Y)
  &= 2X + 5Y,\\
  \label{func1b}
  U(X,Y)
  &= (XY)^{0{.}5},\\
  \label{func1c}
  U(X,Y)
  &= \min(X,Y).
\end{align}

\section{The function~\eqref{func1a}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @SvendTveskæg This doesn't change in any way how the reference is typeset, it only acts on the bookmark, which is just a string.

Comment: Reading the solution, I'm thinking: why not to update the package so that those warnings will not occur anymore? Why the package is not so smart and still produce this kind of disturbing warnings?

Comment: @Sigur Apparently, Heiko never found it and nobody asked him to add it. As I explained elsewhere, `hyperref` already redefines a bunch of commands for making them behave in bookmarks, but adding hundreds of them would slow processing documents. In the case of `\eqref`, adding it seems sensible.

Comment: @egreg Doesn't it change how the reference is typeset? `$\eqref{func1a}$` will give you *math parenthesis*. I think.

Comment: @Manuel No; the expansion of `\eqref` starts with `\textup`, so the parentheses are in text mode.